# Conversion type in printf (with no casting operator)

Tags: c, casting, type-conversion, printf

I'm trying to run the following code for a demonstration of how conversion works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=5;
    int y=2;
    float z;
    printf("x=%d\n", x);
    printf("y=%d\n", y);

    //Doing division as it is
    z= x/y;
    printf("With no preliminar assignment: (z=x/y)\n");
    printf("\"z\" is: %d (integer)  or %lf (double) or %f(float)\n\n\n", z, z, z);

    //Doing assignment before division
    printf("With the assignment: (z=x)\n");
    z=x;
    printf("\"z\" before division is:");
    printf("%d (integer)  or %lf (double) or %f(float)\n", z, z, z);

    //Doing division after assignment
    z/=y;
    printf("\"z\" after division with assignment: (z=z/y)");
    printf(" is: %d (integer)  or %lf (double) or %f(float)\n", z, z, z);

    return 0;
}
```

The OUTPUT is:

```
x=5
y=2
With no preliminar assignment: (z=x/y)
"z" is: 0 (integer)  or 0.000000 (double) or 0.000000(float)


With the assignment: (z=x)
"z" before division is:0 (integer)  or 0.000000 (double) or 0.000000(float)
"z" after division with assignment: (z=z/y) is: 0 (integer)  or 0.000000 (double) or 0.000000(float)
```

This leave me with a doubt, also because my professor at University wrote the following code:

```
int x=5;
int y=2;
float z;

int main (void) {
    z = x / y;
    return 0;
}
```

And for him, z will assume 2.0 (Which is logically correct, but not in printf).

So my final question is, why am I having 0 as result in all the printf?
(I would like to not to use type casting operator)

Comment: the types of the arguments must match the format string. if they don't you have to cast. otherwise it would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: how come line 12 give 0.000000 as double result? Please provide the correct OUTPUT

Comment: I do not modify the OUTPUT, try it yourself & you'll get my result @kalpajagrawalla . So my question remain.

Comment: No, we do not get your result. For “With no preliminar assignment,” I get “"z" is: 73896 (integer)  or 2.000000 (double) or 2.000000(float)”. There is a rule that the **type** of an argument must match the **conversion specifier** in order for the behavior to be defined. When you pass a `float` argument (`z`) for the conversion specification `%d`, you break this rule. At the last, that messes up how passing arguments to `printf` works. That means `printf` gets the wrong data. It behaves differently on different implementations. And it means what is printed is not showing you what is in `z`.

Comment: Correct: “At the last” should have been “At the least.”

Comment: I copy/paste my code to a blank page and it still result 0 in all cases (%d, %f, %fl). I'm using gcc compiler for that with the cmd line **gcc es1.c -o es1.exe**. I'm not understanding why you are having different values from 0.

Comment: I guess that your professor avoided to use any I/O function, suggesting that you should refrain to use `printf()` as a debugger, when we are nearly in 2020 and a debugger is easily available on any platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf()`, as many variadic functions, use a format string to tell to the function which kind of parameters expect on the call stack, **but this doesn't imply that any conversion is actuated on such parameters based on the format string**.

Anyway any decent compiler will warn you about the format/parameters type mismatch, this means that you deliberately ignored them..

Probably you are making a confusion between **argument promotions** and format specifier.

In variable arguments functions the parameters not explicitly defined, those identified by `...`, are handled in a standard way as described in C standard **ISO/IEC 9899:201x, §6.5.2.2 Function calls**. In subparagraph **6** we read:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>   does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on
>   each argument, and arguments that have type `float` are promoted to
>   `double`. **These are called the default argument promotions**.
>
> If the
>   number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the
>   behavior is undefined. If the function is defined with a type that
>   includes a prototype, and either the prototype ends with an ellipsis
>   (, ...) or the types of the arguments after promotion are not
>   compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is
>   undefined. If the function is defined with a type that does not
>   include a prototype, and the types of the arguments after promotion
>   are not compatible with those of the parameters after promotion, the
>   behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:

- > one promoted
  >   type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the
  >   corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in
  >   both types;
- > both types are pointers to qualified or unqualified    > versions of a character type or void.

So if you want have a meaningful output you **must explicetely convert parameters** as in:

```
printf(" is: %d (integer)  or %lf (double) or %f(float)\n", (int)z, z, z);
```

Note that only the cast to `int` is due, leaving the other 2 entries to default promotion that will convert `float` to `double` satisfying what the function expect based on the format string. Without the explicit cast the compiler will promote the variable `z` from `float` to `double`, as per the default argument promotion rules, while the `printf()` code will try to access it as an `int`.

The problem of values all zero in your code is due to the mismatch in the parameters size `int`/`double` that broken the stack unwrap.

Comment: I did not use the cmd line "gcc -Wall ecc...." but now I'm seeing what you was referring and is true (I'm learning C and from now it will become my first action in compiling phase, so thank you). As you suggested, I added "(int)" in all printf func before the first "z"(referred to %d) to specify the integer conversion. So I have another question, the printf() was not outputting the "real" value of z in ALL CASES (%d, %fl, %f) because it was in an undefined behaviour state due to the mismatch between %d (format type) and z (float var.)?

Comment: If you mean before the explicit cast, I gave an explanation in the answer. To go more into the point is that the code that extract the required arguments from the calling stack use the dimension (the `sizeof`) of the parameter type. If in your system `sizeof(int)==4` and `sizeof(double)==8`, the function read the first 4 bytes of the `double` on the stack, and interpreted it as an `int`. If they were 0 you got it. Then the following arguments were accessed at a wrong offset. A complete mess-up.

Answer (score 2):

> why am I having 0 as result in all the printf?

You have an incomplete understanding of the significance of formatting directives in a `printf` format string.  *Above all else* they convey to `printf` the data type of their corresponding arguments, which are not otherwise known to `printf`.  They also specify details of how to format the value, but that is secondary to the question of how to interpret the argument list.  If the directives do not correspond correctly to the actual argument types, then the resulting behavior is wholly undefined.  Certainly `printf` can produce surprising output in such cases,<sup>*</sup> but in principle, *anything* could happen.

Thus a statement such as this ...

> ```
>    printf("\"z\" is: %d (integer)  or %lf (double) or %f(float)\n\n\n", z, z, z);
> ```

... where conversion directives specify different, incompatible types for the same value, is *always* incorrect.  One way to correct it would be to convert the arguments to the correct types, like so:

```
    printf("\"z\" is: %d (integer)  or %lf (double) or %f(float)\n\n\n", (int) z, (double) z, z);
```

But that's not particularly useful for your apparent purpose.  It appears that all the conversions you're actually interested in happen before or during each assignment to `z`, so nothing is gained by considering the results of afterward converting that result to other data types.  This, then, would be a better correction:

```
    printf("\"z\" is: %f(float)\n\n\n", z);
```

Alternatively, to separate the effects of conversion during assignment from the effects of conversion during arithmetic computation, you could perform *different* assignments to variables of the different types of interest.  For example,

```
    int x = 5;
    int y = 2;
    int zi;
    double zd;
    float zf;

    // ...

    zi = x / y;
    zd = x / y;
    zf = x / y;

    // ...

    printf("\"z\" is: %d (integer)  or %lf (double) or %f(float)\n\n\n", zi, zd, zf);
```

---

<sup>*</sup> This is the answer to the actual question posed.

Comment: `float`s are promoted to `double`s so there is not need to cast a `float` to `double`. Or do you do this to keep things clearer?

Comment: You are quite correct, @alk, including your guess about my intention.  It is not necessary to go into the details of the default argument promotions to answer the question, and I don't think doing so would improve the answer relative to using a cast to explicitly express conformance with the type-matching requirement.